# Capture location from background and upload that to cloud or save to local storage in android

Tags: android, service, location

I want to create an android application which can capture device location even when  the app is not running. I had tried to make an app that returns data from service to main thread. That app is working fine when the app is running but if the app is closed it is not capturing any location.

I have attached my service class. Now it is just capturing location and updates the UI. it is **working** even when the application is in **pause**. but it is **not working** when the application is **destroyed**.

```
public class DeviceLocationService extends Service {

private LocationListener listener;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();
private int count = 0;

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    listener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Config.LOCATION_INTENT_FILTER);
            HashMap<Object,Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
            Log.d(TAG, "onAccuracyChanged: "+location.getAccuracy());

            hashMap.put("latitude",location.getLatitude());
            hashMap.put("longitude",location.getLongitude());
            hashMap.put("accuracy",location.getAccuracy());
            hashMap.put("provider",location.getProvider());

            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(hashMap);
            i.putExtra("location_data",jo.toString());
            Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged: "+jo.toString());
            sendBroadcast(i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onStatusChanged: provider "+provider);
            Log.d(TAG, "onStatusChanged: status "+status);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: "+provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        }
    };

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (locationManager != null) {
        //noinspection MissingPermission
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,listener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0,listener);
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Add code snippet you have tried. share issues you are facing. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should use WorkManager for this

Comment: I have attached my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run your service in background you need to use foreground service.

add below code in your service

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        startMyOwnForeground();
    else
        startForeground(1, new Notification());
    return START_STICKY;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void startMyOwnForeground(){
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.simpleapp";
    String channelName = "My Background Service";
    NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
    chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
    chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    assert manager != null;
    manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setContentTitle("App is running in background")
            .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .build();
    startForeground(2, notification);
}
```

and start service with below code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        startForegroundService(new Intent(this,DeviceLocationService.class));
    } else
        startService(new Intent(this,DeviceLocationService.class));
```

Comment: what will be the best practice to save the location for current season. If I want to create a travel Tracker app and run my app in background. after the journey i want to check the location details of my travel.